# Analysis: Show that $f(x)=x$ (short proof) in interval.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

Let $a>0 $ and $f:[-a,a]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous with $f(a)=a$, and $f(-a)=-a$.  Suppose $f'(x)$ exists in $(-a,a)$ with $f'(x)\leq 1$ in $(-a,a)$.  Show that $f(x)=x$ in $(-a,a)$.

Attempt: So I know that the function is continuous and I know that the derivative exists and is less than or equal to 1.

I was thinking that perhaps this is related to the Intermediate Value Theorem which states that Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.  Suppose that $f(a)\neq f(b)$, and that the real number $v$ lies between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.  Then there is a point $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=v$.

So we have the conditions are indeed satisfied. However, I don't really know how to formally or directly apply it or how to use the condition that the $f'(x)\leq 1$.  Does this imply $f(x)\leq x $?  I'm honestly confused.  I could really use some help.  Thanks.

Comment: Try using the Mean Value Theorem. The derivative is bounded above by $1$, but in total, the function seems to grow at an average rate of $1$. If the function's derivative ever drops below $1$, then it has to increase impossibly quickly to make up for it.

Comment: $f'(x)\leq 1$ implies $f(x) - f(-a) = \int_{-a}^{x}f'(t)dt \leq \int_{-a}^{x}dt = x + a$.

Comment: @See-WooLee We don't know $f'$ is integrable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x)=x-f(x)$, for all $x\in[-a,a]$.

$g$ is differentiable in $(-a,a)$, and :

$$\forall x\in(-a,a),\,g'(x)=1-f'(x)\ge0$$

This proves that $g$ is non decreasing on $(-a,a)$ and, by continuity, on $[-a,a]$. But $g(-a)=g(a)=0$, hence $g=0$.

Comment: Nice so just quick clarification how does g=0 explicitly show f(x)=x

Comment: If the endpoints are 0 does that mean the whole function is 0?

Comment: @rain : g is a non decreasing function which starts at 0 and ends at ... 0. So it must vanish everywhere !

Comment: Ah got that part so g being 0 mean 0=x-f(x) which means x=f(x).  I'm just trying to understand the steps.  How do you know g is differentiable in [-a,a]?

Comment: @rain: You supposed that $f$ is differentiable in $]-a,a[$ (or that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x\in]-a,a[$, which means the same thing !). So $g$ appears to be the difference between two differentiable functions.

Comment: also what do you mean ]-a,a[ .  I'm not familar with this notation?

Comment: He means $(-a, a)$.

Comment: @rain: Oh ! That's right, sorry. French common notation ;-) Editing...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have some point $b \in (-a, a)$ such that $f(b) < b$. Then, applying the Mean Value Theorem to the interval $[b, a]$, we obtain some $c \in (b, a)$ such that
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(a) - f(b)}{a - b} = \frac{a - f(b)}{a - b} > \frac{a - b}{a - b} = 1.$$
This is a contradiction. Therefore $f(b) \ge b$ for all $b \in (-a, a)$.

Similarly, if $f(b) > b$, then looking at $[-a, b]$, we get some $c \in (-a, b)$ such that
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(-a)}{b + a} = \frac{f(b) + a}{b + a} > \frac{b + a}{b + a} = 1.$$
Similarly, a contradiction. Thus $f(b) = b$ for all $b \in (-a, a)$.

Comment: I understand the proof but why did you specifically choose the intervals [b,a], and [-a,b]?  Thanks.

Comment: So for my example I would suppose f(x)<x and use the interval [x,a], then? Try to show a contradiction to get f(x)>=x?

Comment: I used these intervals because I had to. There are two cases: where the point $(b, f(b))$ lies above or below the line $y = x$. In the former case, it means the function grew too quickly initially, so on the initial line segment $[-a, b]$, there has to be a contradiction with the MVT. In the latter case, the function needs to grow to quickly to make it back to $(a, a)$, so MVT is used on the final line segment $[b, a]$.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks  Instead of b, I would use x though right?

Comment: If you like. I guess I was falling back on the old conventions of using $a, b, c$ for intervals, and the Intermediate/Mean Value Theorems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assume that $f$ is differentiable. Define:
$$g(x)=f(x)-x$$
Your hypothesis says that $g(a)=g(-a)=0$ and that $g^{\prime}(x)\le 0$ for every $x \in (-a,a)$. Together, these conditions imply that $g(x)\le 0$ in the interval. Now, assume that there is a point $z$ in the interval where we have strict inequality. Say $g(z)=-\epsilon<0$. Since $g(a)=0$, the Mean Value Theorem for differentiable functions (notice: the Mean one, not the Intermediate Value Theorem!) guarantees that there exists a second point, say $y \in (z,a)$ s.t. $g^{\prime}(y)=\dfrac{f(a)-f(z)}{a-z}>0$. But this contradicts the fact that $g\prime$ is non-positive in $(-a,a)$.

Comment: How does my hypothesis get g'(x)<0.  I'm not sure about this part.  Thanks.